How to translate points on a path relative to two other points?
I'm trying to make a curved line move relative to the movement of a straight line.
I'm thinking that I want the points on the curved line to keep their relative positions to the two points on the straight line but I can't figure out how to do it.
Constraint: the length of the straight line (from A to B) will stay the same. So point A moves around point B in a circle. (I managed to figure this part out already.)
If point A is moved, than points C, D and E should keep their relative positions to both points A and B.  the distance between C,D, and E could stretch but I would like to keep their distances to A, and B roughly similar.
For example if the lines start like one of these:

And then I move point A to the right, then the lines should look roughly like this afterward:


It is alright if the curved line distorts it's shape so long as when point A is back where it was in the beginning all the points on the curved line are also back at their original positions.
